# Need a way to prevent log shipping from kicking users out

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

We have SQL Server 2012.  A service we use requires us to use log shipping, however we are tired of having users being kicked offline every 15 minutes.

Are there any creative ways to get around this (I believe it cannot be stopped) but perhaps setting up replication & log shipping is that possible?

Somehow having two instances of the same database so when one goes down for log shipping the secondary is automatically used.

Just looking for any creative way to get around users being kicked off during log shipping.

Comment: Are you saying that the user are being kicked off from A: the database form which the logs are being shipped from or B: kicked off the database to which the logs are being shipped ?

Comment: Highly recommend to read, understand and implement it first in test environment - [**readable secondaries on a budget**](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/sql-performance/readable-secondaries-on-a-budget) written by @aaronbertrand.

Comment: @armitage the database the logs are being applied to.  We can't touch the server they are being shipped from.

Comment: @kin I read through a lot of it and trying to understand it.  Is this solution possible if we can't touch the database that sens us logs?  That is all handled via third party.  They FTP us the logs.  It sounded like in the article we needed the "boss" server on our end.

Comment: @JamesWilson then you are going to have problems. Its something that you should be fully managing - if you want to go for that solution. If you want the secondary to be available, why cant you choose transactional replication ?

Comment: @Kin I'm not sure what we can do.  We're just accepting what they give us and looking for improvements.  They manage the database and send us logs.  I believe we set up a database on our end to apply those logs to, but none of us here are really DBA's just programmers looking for solutions.

Comment: The vendor you are working with sounds horrible. That's besides the point though. Unless the vendor is willing to change how they send you data, the best solution will be to restore the logs less. Your data will be more stale but you'd be reducing the user kick-outs to something more manageable. Depending upon your need, you could restore the logs over night and leave the database static all day.

Comment: They FTP your side the transaction logs and then those are applied to the DB on your end. This means that DB is in standby then and your side is only able to run SELECT statements against it.  When log shipping transactions are restored to the DB, it disconnects all sessions.  If you can live with your side only restoring once a day rather than every 15 minutes and those results your side provides being 24 hours old is acceptable, see if that's a feasible solution. Your side would then ensure your processes do not run during the once a day transaction log shipping restores until it's finished.